# Action bar title doesn't change

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have MainActivity with Navigation Drawer.
Here is two functions from MainActivity.java

```
    @Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    Fragment fragment;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    switch(position) {
        default:
        case 0:
            fragment = new AlarmClockFragment().newInstance(position);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new SettingsFragment().newInstance(position);
            break;
    }
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 0:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
    }
}
```

In each fragment I have methods to change Action bar title. I do it like that:

I have:

```
private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
private int mSectionNumber = 0;
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
```

I get ARG_SECTION_NUMBER:

```
    public static AlarmClockFragment newInstance(int param1) {
    AlarmClockFragment fragment = new AlarmClockFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, param1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Than

```
    @Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(mSectionNumber);
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

Code is similiar to both Fragments (AlarmCLockFragment and SettingsFragment), but it doesn't work.

If I don't use variable `mSectionNumber` and just write `((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(0);` all will be nice. So I can't find a problem with initialization `mSectionNumber`.

setTitle() here:

```
public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}
```

onCreate() in Fragments:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mSectionNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is setTitle() ?

Comment: There is in restoreActionBar() in MainActivity.java

Comment: where do you call it from? :) Looks like setTitle() should be in `onSectionAttached()`

Comment: It is not a solution, because setTitle is correct and it called. I can write '((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(0);' and it works.

Comment: RE: mSectionNumber - in Fragment's `onCreate()` or `onAttach()` there should be `mSectionNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, def_value);`

Comment: Yes, I use it (updated post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just let the Fragments set the title?

In `onActivityCreated` or similar call:

```
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(...)
```

Edit: The solution to your specific issue is that `onAttach` is called before `onCreate` in the Fragment lifecycle. Here's a good resource to use: http://staticfree.info/~steve/complete_android_fragment_lifecycle.png

Comment: But it doesn't solve my problem. I'm probably wrong in topic title. 
Why mSectionNumber can't updated?

Comment: Well it looks like your code is really overcomplicated. You're passing a position integer to the fragment, which is notifying the activity that it is attached and passing the integer back. Either set `mTitle` in `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected` or just let the fragments set the title. Alexander highlighted your bug in confusing `mSectionNumber` and the argument passed into the fragment constructor. `mSectionNumber` is always 0.

Comment: I understood about title, but what if I just want to delivery data from activity to fragment? (position, for example)
I use mSectionNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, def_value); in Fragment's onCreate(), but it still doesn't update.

Comment: `onAttach` is called before `onCreate`